# Why do I get a KeyError when using pandas apply?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, keyerror

I'm working on the kaggle Outbrain competition, and all datasets referenced in my code can be found at https://www.kaggle.com/c/outbrain-click-prediction/data.

On to the problem: I have a dataframe with columns `['document_id', 'category_id', 'confidence_level']`. I would like to add a fourth column, `'max_cat'`, that returns the `'category_id'` value that corresponds to the greatest `'confidence_level'` value for the row's `'document_id'`.

```py
import pandas as pd
main_folder = r'...filepath\data_location' + '\\'
test = pd.read_csv(main_folder + 'documents_categories.csv\documents_categories.csv',nrows=1000)

def find_max(row,the_df,groupby_col,value_col,target_col):
    return the_df[the_df[groupby_col]==row[groupby_col]].loc[the_df[value_col].idxmax()][target_col]

test['max_cat'] = test.apply(lambda x: find_max(x,test,'document_id','confidence_level','category_id'))
```

This gives me the error:

```
KeyError: ('document_id', 'occurred at index document_id')
```

Can anyone help explain either why this error occurred, or how to achieve my goal in a more efficient manner?

Comment: pass `axis=1`: `test.apply(lambda x: find_max(x,test,'document_id','confidence_level','category_id'), axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, that fix led me to a second problem with an index mis-match that I was able to solve by myself. I'm also new to stackoverflow, so I'm not familiar with etiquette/how to give you credit for nudging me in the right direction. Appreciate the help!

Comment: basically the issue here is that `apply` on a df works column-wise by default (`axis=0`), your function is expecting a row so you need to pass `axis=1`, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: @EdChum I think your comment should be posted as the answer for the sake of clarity

Comment: if x is your row, do you need to pass x[index_value] to access the value? 

in my case, it was: df.apply(lambda x: func(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)

I was applying a custom function to the first and second columns and I wanted to run it across all rows.

Answer (score 63):

As answered by EdChum in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960728/pandas-apply-key-error#comment67201157_39960728). The issue is that `apply` works column wise by default (see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)). Therefore, the column names cannot be accessed.

To specify that it should be applied to each row instead, `axis=1` must be passed:

```
test.apply(lambda x: find_max(x,test,'document_id','confidence_level','category_id'), axis=1)
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: It looks like you have misplaced some parenthesis or coma, because it assumes that axis is a parameter of lambda instead of being a parameter of apply

Comment: There are 2 versions of apply. One works on Series, the other works on Dataframes. Only DataFrames' apply function has "axis" as a keyword. You must be calling apply on a Series, which have only one axis and thus no "axis" argument

Answer (score 1):

##### Why `axis=1`?

To expand on Oriol's answer, `test` is a dataframe and some of the parameters that are passed to `find_max()` - `'document_id'`, `'confidence_level'` and `'category_id'` are column labels, so the function should be called on each row. To do that `axis=1` should be passed.

##### I still get `KeyError: 0`. What gives?

For the given dataset, even after including `axis=1`, a `KeyError: 0` is raised. The reason is that `idxmax()` is called on the entire column (`the_df[value_col]`) so returns the first index of the max values in the entire dataframe but that index is being used to filter a slice of the dataframe (`the_df[the_df[groupby_col]==row[groupby_col]]`). In short, the dataframe doesn't have the key 0.

If we debug the code a bit, by printing what the slice looks like:

```py
def find_max(row,the_df,groupby_col,value_col,target_col):
    x = the_df[the_df[groupby_col]==row[groupby_col]]
    idx = the_df[value_col].idxmax()
    print('slice:\n', x, end='\n\n')
    print('index:', idx)
    return x.loc[idx][target_col]
```

it outputs

```
slice:
    document_id  category_id  confidence_level
2      1524246         1807              0.92
3      1524246         1608              0.07

index: 0
```

As you can see, this slice's indices are `[2, 3]`, yet `idx=0`, so when `slice.loc[idx]` is tried, the KeyError is raised since there is no index `0`.

##### How to perform the filtering correctly and more efficiently

To answer OP's original request

> how to achieve my goal in a more efficient manner?

Since the goal is to

> return the 'category_id' value that corresponds to the greatest 'confidence_level' value for the row's 'document_id'.

it can be done by transforming the `idxmax()` across groups using `groupby.transform`.

```py
df['max_cat'] = df.loc[df.groupby('document_id')['confidence_level'].transform('idxmax'), 'category_id'].tolist()
```

For the given input, the first 6 rows of the output looks as follows:

[image: result]